# Get App Instance using process handle of Acrobat DC in C#

Tags: c#, acrobat-sdk

I have **process handle** of Adobe Acrobat Pro DC process instance running, how can I get **AcroExch.App** object using process handle in C#.

Comment: Worked quiet long time for it, but unable to find a solution for it, For word, I simply use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")` but unable to find solution for this.

Comment: I tried this with, _Acrobat.Document.DC_ and _AcroExch.Document.DC_ but no success, Is there any other way to retrieve COM Object from ROT and cast it to AcroExch.App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that, *Unfortunately*, Acrobat DC SDK, works only with either Adobe Acrobat Pro/Standard version. Doesn't support Acrobat Reader DC.

So, I managed to retrieve reference pointing running instance of Acrobat Pro DC using following piece of code,

```
Type PDFType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AcroExch.App");
CAcroApp AcroAppObj = Activator.CreateInstance(PDFType) as CAcroApp;

AcroAppObj.Show();
CAcroAVDoc AvDocObj = AcroAppObj.GetActiveDoc() as CAcroAVDoc;

CAcroPDDoc PdDocObj = AvDocObj.GetPDDoc() as CAcroPDDoc;

string fileName = PdDocObj.GetFileName();
```